# SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression:

Tags: javascript

I'm pretty sure my regex is correct, but anytime I try to test the code, I get an invalid regular expression error with a nothing to repeat at the end.

I'll attach the code below

```
 function checkPhoneNumber(phoneNumber) {

    let phoneNumberValidation = RegExp("(\+1[ ]?)((\(?[0-9]{3}\)?[-\. ]?))([0-9]{3}[-\. ]?)([0-9]{4})");
    if (phoneNumberValidation.test(phoneNumber)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please post the actual error, along with test data & expected results.

Comment: Don't use the `RegExp` function unless you're creating the regular expression dynamically. Use a regexp literal in `//`. Otherwise you'll run into lots of problems due to backslash being both a string and regexp escape character.

Comment: @Barmar I removed the literal and it finally worked. Thank you so much.